# Change system volume in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone, volume

Up until now I thought that changing the system volume from your app is impossible, until recently a new app called Quite Hours (http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/quiet-hours/f347a36b-80c0-430f-8631-e55046ee5a2a) actually did just that in a very neat way.

Does anyone please know how to do that programmatically? I tried using the MediaElement or the xna MediaPlayer and the backgroundAudioPlayer and nothing worked. Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Wow! I have no idea how the developer did this. This will deserve some kind of investigation!

Comment: I have been searching for hours now, I really thought it was impossible, yet it works in the app and it doesn't mess with the player controls!

Comment: Really, no idea here... And it also can affect the volume from the background? This is really weird!

Comment: Same here :) yes with the full version, the background agent does all the work! It's really strange and I hope someone could help because it's very interesting!

Comment: I have already contacted the developer, I hope he will give us a peek on his magical abilities :-) !

Comment: Very nice of you! thanks! I certainly hope so :) and yes this is truly magical :D

Comment: Bad news, he said he can't disclose any information because it is a company's app... But there still has to be a way to find out!

Comment: I was expecting as much :( I tried to ask the question in windows phone developer forums and Nokia dev forums as well and no one seems to know of a way to do this. One guy from MSFT said they either found a loop-hole or have some kind of partnership! This is getting on my nerves haha

Comment: Partnership? That would be pretty unfair :-) ! Given that also their other apps aren't THAT incredible. (not saying they are not good, but not that would deserve such a special treatement ;-) ) I think that it is not a special permission, but a hack. As I had read even the companies working closest to Microsoft (excluding basically just Nokia) are given the same APIs as all other developers no matter what.

Comment: Yes But I don't know what to believe anymore, but check out that answer, I will try it soon after take the exam tomorrow, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/0cc4ec59-2c3d-4e2d-aa84-36ca602ea05f/change-system-volume-in-windows-phone-8?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion they used this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681688(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Yes, it seems so. Another app with the same functionality just appeared - http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/volume-manager/b128c4c2-46d3-4343-aa68-8f1ea3e88434

Answer (score 3):

The developers of the apps mentioned in the OP were able to change system volume under WP8.0. Apparently whatever method they used has now been disabled under WP8.1. The following apps now display disclaimers that they no longer work on Windows Phone 8.1: [Quiet Hours](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/quiet-hours/f347a36b-80c0-430f-8631-e55046ee5a2a) and [Volume Manager](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/volume-manager/b128c4c2-46d3-4343-aa68-8f1ea3e88434)

They direct to the following page to vote to allow this functionality: [Windows Phone Dev User Voice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1908267-extend-the-api-to-query-phone-volume-and-vibration)

Additionally please read the following thread on the MSDN forum: [MSDN change system volume Windows Phone 8](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0cc4ec59-2c3d-4e2d-aa84-36ca602ea05f/change-system-volume-in-windows-phone-8?forum=wpdevelop). This functionality was likely achieved using WASAPI (which I have personally tried, and failed, it does not work, comment if you want my code to try it.), or the developers of the volume apps might have had access to [AudioClientRestricted.h](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-US/OEM/docs/Driver_Components/Restricted_audio_categories). If one had that h file, one would have access to system volume under WP8.1, so I somehow doubt the developers used the h file designated for OEMs because it would work un 8.1.

Talking with James Dailey (who works @ MSFT) indicates it is technically possible using WASAPI [ISimpleAudioVolume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316531(v=vs.85).aspx) If you read @ the bottom of that page there is a comment indicating you must use [IAudioEndpointVolume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368062(v=vs.85).aspx)

Added note from James Dailey @ MSFT:

> AFAIK there is no good way to manipulate the global audio level on
>   Windows Phone 8.1 (WP8.1). Theoretically you can change the audio
>   volume of any app that uses the default audio session “zero”. However,
>   if  the app chooses to initialize it’s audio session with a custom
>   GUID you will not have access to the session volume for its custom
>   audio session. Again this is theoretical based on my knowledge of the
>   inner workings of WASAPI. I’ve never actually tried it on the phone.
>   To manipulate the audio volume of apps using audio session “zero” you
>   simply initialize your IAudioClient with an AudioSessionGuid parameter
>   of “{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}”. You can then use
>   ISimpleAudioVolume::SetMasterVolume to set the volume for this audio
>   session.   You will need to use C++ / Cx since we do not support
>   calling WASAPI from managed code.

Answer (score 0):

There currently is no API available for controlling the system volume. You can however control the volume in the elements of your application (via the classes MediaElement, BackgroundAudioAgent).
You can also control the volume on sound effects of your application using XNA API.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195052%28v=xnagamestudio.30%29.aspx

Comment: I posted the answer in the comments. There IS a library.