# Set system volume in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Can I set system volume from code behind?
I know that in WP8 no way to do this. Maybe in WP8.1 ms added some api for system volume access?

Comment: Did you [try searching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083032/change-system-volume-in-windows-phone-8)?

Comment: yes, this is for WP8 but I looking for WP8.1

Comment: Given there's still no built-in way for WP8.1, won't the workaround from WP8 mentioned in said question just work?

Comment: No, it won't. It is currently not possible to change the system volume in WP8.1.

Comment: look over here if it helps you out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448019(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The only way to access it is via C++ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681688(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible I have tried using the WASAPI drivers from Microsoft.

As an added note quoting from MSFT support James Dailey:

> AFAIK there is no good way to manipulate the global audio level on
>   Windows Phone 8.1 (WP8.1). Theoretically you can change the audio
>   volume of any app that uses the default audio session “zero”. However,
>   if  the app chooses to initialize it’s audio session with a custom
>   GUID you will not have access to the session volume for its custom
>   audio session. Again this is theoretical based on my knowledge of the
>   inner workings of WASAPI. I’ve never actually tried it on the phone.
>   To manipulate the audio volume of apps using audio session “zero” you
>   simply initialize your IAudioClient with an AudioSessionGuid parameter
>   of “{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}”. You can then use
>   ISimpleAudioVolume::SetMasterVolume to set the volume for this audio
>   session.   You will need to use C++ / Cx since we do not support
>   calling WASAPI from managed code.

The above suggestion does not work.