# Sound volume level in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

How to programmatically get 'Media + apps' sound volume level?

[image]

Comment: It's not supported, you can check here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383944/set-system-volume-in-windows-phone-8-1

Comment: @Sajeetharan it is not supported to set, but he asked to get, it is supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Volume
```

Comment: Always returns 1. I think it is some local app volume value.

Comment: @x2. the value is between 1 and 0 - you are possibly casting it to some integer.

Comment: @x2. set your slider range between somevalue from 0 to 1

Comment: I just call `Debug.WriteLine(BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Volume);` No matter how I change volume level it always returns 1.

Comment: @x2. did you try my answer?

Comment: @Sajeetharan, I don't use any sliders.

Comment: @x2. then you need to cast it to float as ivan told